# Navigation to Specific ViewController After Interacting With Push

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, apple-push-notifications

I'm having a tough time finding any good information about the best way to manage navigation flow when the user enters an iOS application by interacting with a push notification.

In my case, I have a UITabController where each tab has a root UINavigationController. For example, let's say the push should lead me to the 2nd tab. To complicate things a bit, depending on the push's json, I may want to start at the root, OR I may want to populate a stack of viewControllers with the last being initialized in a particular way due to variables in the json.

The question can be reframed somewhat conceptually: what is the proper way to populate a NavigationController's stack and display the n-1 ViewController when a user activate's the application through a PushNotification (both from a terminated and a background state). Which delegate method(s) are of use, and how can one avoid race conditions since it's likely ViewController's will be uninitialized.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> AppDelegate.h

Make a UITabBarController Object in AppDelegate.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

> AppDelegate.m

Define a Method to Handle Remote Push Notification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        CustomViewController1 *view1 = [[CustomViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController1" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *view1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];

        CustomViewController2 *view2 = [[CustomViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController2" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *view2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view2];

        CustomViewController3 *view3 = [[CustomViewController3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController3" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *view3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view3];

        NSArray *arrNavControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view2, view2, view2, nil];

        // Set here CustomViewController On Which you want to Naviagte
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
        [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` class has a property `viewControllers` which is an array of `UIViewController`s where the last member of the array is the one on the top of the stack of navigation controller. So the steps are following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let tabController = UITabBarController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let navCon1 = UINavigationController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let navCon2 = UINavigationController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let viewCon1 = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    let viewCon2 = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    navCon2.setViewControllers([viewCon1, viewCon2], animated: false)

    tabController.setViewControllers([navCon1, navCon2], animated: false)
    tabController.selectedIndex = 1

    window?.rootViewController = tabController

}
```

This instantiates `UITabBarController`, instantiates `UINavigationController` and sets its 2 view controllers (remember the last one in the array is on top of the stack) without animation and then adds the navigation controller to the `UITabBarController`.

This is just a showcase, but controllers can be inited from storyboard as well using `UIStoryboard`'s 
`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(_:)`